# angular2 and typescript error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hammer.js

I am trying to create an angular 2 application and use hammerjs for the touch gestures.
Currently I am trying to combine the quickstarter application from: [Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)    with the hammerjs application from: [Hammerjs sample](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2).

I keep getting an error:

```
http://localhost:3000/npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:33 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js
Error loading http://localhost:3000/npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js
Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
```

My systemjs.config.js file:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
// DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
transpiler: 'ts',
typescriptOptions: {
  tsconfig: true
},
meta: {
  'typescript': {
    "exports": "ts"
  }
},
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
  'ts':                         'npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
  'typescript':                 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js',

},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './app.component.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
   });
})(this);
```

My folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

mypackage.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation,     supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
"build": "tsc -p src/",
"build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
"build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
"serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
"serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
"prestart": "npm run build",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
"pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
"e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
"preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
"protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
"pretest": "npm run build",
"test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start     karma.conf.js\"",
"pretest:once": "npm run build",
"test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
"lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I installed all npm install modules.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you run an npm install on the command line? What is the content of your package.json file? It is not finding this library: npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js

Comment: I updated the question. I did the npm install and do have all dependencies. by the way I do not have a plugin.js in my node_modules/typescript folde.

Comment: this is the library you are missing: https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript.  This isn't the typescript library, it is a 3rd party library.

Comment: Claies - I was not aware of the plugin, now it is installed and I am having trouble with my System.config setup with this plugin. Can you see what should be set there?

Comment: If you really need to use the missing plugin, please go to its github repository (https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript) and read the documentation.If you don't need it, please remove the line in the system.config.js file to see what happens. This is what the plugin is for, "A plugin for SystemJS which enables you to System.import TypeScript files directly. The files are transpiled in the browser and compilation errors written to the console."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need this (from the documentation for ypeScript loader for SystemJS): If you are using SystemJS without JSPM (you are using npm), add SystemJS map configuration for plugin-typescript and typescript:

```
SystemJS.config({
  packages: {
    "ts": {
      "main": "plugin.js"
    },
    "typescript": {
      "main": "lib/typescript.js",
      "meta": {
        "lib/typescript.js": {
          "exports": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  map: {
    "ts": "path/to/plugin-typescript/lib",
    "typescript": "path/to/typescript"
  },
  transpiler: 'ts'
});
```